# Stopping anchor href navigation when the anchor element is being dragged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following: http://jsfiddle.net/15md3dLz/8/

Which leverages a library to animate / event when liking/disliking.

The markup looks like this:

```
<div id="tinderslide">
  <ul>
    <li class="pane1">
      <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div>Miami Beach</div>
        <div class="like"></div>
        <div class="dislike"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="pane2">
      <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div>Miami Beach</div>
        <div class="like"></div>
        <div class="dislike"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="pane3">
      <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div>Miami Beach</div>
        <div class="like"></div>
        <div class="dislike"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="pane4">
      <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div>Miami Beach</div>
        <div class="like"></div>
        <div class="dislike"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="pane5">
      <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div>Miami Beach</div>
        <div class="like"></div>
        <div class="dislike"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My problem is that when I release the click to either like, dislike, or drop the card, the link is navigated.  I'd like to prevent this and have the link work only on click/tap, not on drag.

Comment: Instead of putting the anchor around the image, can you do this: `<a href="#"><div>Miami Beach</div></a>`.  That way you can drag the image without following the link.  Or does the HTML have to be like that?

Comment: @UndoingTech the html has to remain - as there are other elements that also serve as the "card" that need to respond to both dragging and clicking.

Answer (score 1):

use event.preventDefault() method to stop event bubbling .example   .

you can replace your code with below lines for each li:-
     
        
        Miami Beach